# Rational Canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could anyone explain me in detail how to find out a rational canonical form of any $n\times n$ matrix?

Please explain with an example.

P.S: I am an amateur in linear algebra.

Thanks

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalCanonicalForm.html and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEuf8E_OSB4

Comment: even before this, I would suggest you to see why do we use rational canonical forms, when we already have Jordan Canonical Forms... What is the problem with Jordan Canonical Forms???

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: If your base field is not algebraically closed, there are matrices which do not have a Jordan normal form. Rational normal forms exist for all base fields.

Comment: @azimut : I was expecting answer from Mr. Bala teja the OP... I am familiar with the criterion of RCF.... That was a question and not a doubt :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Oh, I see :) Seems that I didn't read your comment too carefully...

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi: Please consider to make an answer out of your comment...To avoid that this question stays unanswered.

Comment: This is described in all detail over here: mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalCanonicalForm.html and youtube.com/watch?v=PEuf8E_OSB4

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I just wanted to learn about RCF as it is basic part of my course (Multivariable control theory). If you can, please elaborate how JCF or RCF is useful for my course and a comparison of both. Thanks for your interest btw.

Comment: @Balateja : I am not at all familiar with "Multivariable Control Theory". You do not need to have much background to study JCF. If you have any familiarity with module theory, i suggest you to read Rational Canonical Form Part in the book Abstract Algebra by Dummit foote. As explained above, Jordan canonical forms are less complicated way of representation of a given matrix when we know that all eigen values are in given field and if we do not have all eigen values in given field then we go for Rational Canonical Forms which are not so "good looking"/easy to solve than JCF.

Comment: the key concepts is that of the **companion matrix** of a matrix

Answer (score 5):

A straight trick to get the *rational form* for a matrix $A$, is to know that the rational form comes from the **minimal polynomial** of the matrix $A$. And knowing that the minimal polynomial can be deduced from the **Jordan form** of $A$, one obtains the rational form converting each of the Jordan blocks of $A$ into its **companion matrix**.

In a while I will adjoint an  example.

Comment: rational form are also known as [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form ]

Comment: a good prototype example is [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form#Example ]