# Why should I learn rational canonical form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I just want to ask why should i learn to find rational canonical form of a matrix.

I learnt to find Jordan canonical form of a matrix since I needed to check whether the two matrices are similar or not.

What is the use of rational canonical form which Jordan canonical is insufficient in.

And what are some interesting things that a rational canonical form implies.

I am waiting eagerly for this answer

Comment: From MathWorld: "Any square matrix T has a canonical form without any need to extend the field of its coefficients. For instance, if the entries of T are rational numbers, then so are the entries of its rational canonical form. (The Jordan canonical form may require complex numbers.) "

Comment: Nice point. Anything else?

Comment: Nope, that's pretty much it. Jordan canonical form requires extending scalars, rational canonical form does not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine if two square matrices with the same size are similar, you can determine if they have the same rational canonical form. They are similar if and only if they have the same canonical form. You can't do that with the Jordan canonical form without finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial, which will be quite hard in general.

Comment: What do you mean by " with the same side" ??

Comment: @AbhishekChandra I meant “size”, not “side”. I've edited my answer.

Comment: By the way can you refer me from where can I learn to find rational canonical form of a matrix ?

Comment: @AbhishekChandra Please read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470480/rational-canonical-form) and its answer. Also, read [this article](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/9/253.pdf).